# Cocos2d CCNode.positionInPoints gives percentage value not position?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I think i have a simple problem. I am making a project in sprite builder, and I tend to lay things out with percentages.

But in Xcode when I look for the "position in points" it will give me the percentage (i.e. a number 0-1). If I change it from percentages in spritbuilder it works fine, but I would like to keep things in percentage.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's the position *type*.  From the [reference](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCNode.html):

> By using the `positionType` property you can specify how a node’s
>   position is interpreted. For instance, if you set the type to
>   `CCPositionTypeNormalized` a position value of (0.5, 0.5) will place the
>   node in the center of its parent’s container. The container is
>   specified by the parent’s `contentSize`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But after looking at it a while it looks like node.positioninpoints is returning a normalized value. This is not right, right?